# Does MinGW create object files when compiling multisource program files?

Tags: c++, c, mingw

I heard that when you compile multi-source files with gcc on Linux, gcc creates object files *.o for every source code file, so you don't need to recompile all files when you change only one. I'm using MinGW on Win7 x64 and MinGW doesn't create any object file.

main.c

```
//main.c
#include "header.h"
int main(void)
{
    Message();
    return 0;
}
```

source.c

```
//source.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

void Message()
{
    printf("Hello World...\n");
}
```

header.h

```
//header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <stdio.h>

void Message(void);

#endif
```

If I place those files on desktop and compile with command: `gcc main.c source.c -o program`
I only get program.exe, not any .obj files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `MinGW` does save the temporary files. The path for the temporary files will be equal to the `%TEMP%` variable in your machine. You can also view the temporary files through this command

```
gcc -o example.out source.c main.c --save-temps
```

**EDIT**

Corrected one typo. The path would be `%TEMP%` and not `PATH`

Comment: @user1654209 Thanks.. I corrected my response. It would be the `%TEMP%` directory and not `PATH`. I had done a mistake.. +1 for your response..

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of GCC is the same on Linux as with MinGW on Windows in this regard.

You can specifically tell gcc to produce object files for linking later:

```
gcc -c main.c source.c          # compile to object files
gcc -o program main.o source.o  # link the object files and produce an executable
```